# Can someone get the current password of database if they have physical access on the Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a Web base System and I'm using Xampp on it, my database has a password and I'm accessing it through phpMyAdmin.

I have some people working on the same machine where the Web base System is running, we're using the System for specific task.

One thing I'm afraid of is if they can get or find out the password of database (these not include overriding or resetting the password).

Since they are physically accessing the Server, is is possible to get or lets say decrypt the current password? if so, what are the possible ways?

I want to be aware of it and I want to improve the security of the System base on the method that they can do.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this really for? PHP MyAdmin and SQL Server are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several layers of security here.

I believe the correct answer to your question is "no, this isn't a risk," but a thorough answer will address all the possible means of exposure.

### System accounts

Your operating system has user accounts. This is how you, other users, and various system services (such as the MySQL server itself) authenticate to the operating system. It's a good practice to not share user accounts. These passwords are stored in a salted and hashed form on the server and are not recoverable or reversible (at least, for the purposes of this discussion). There is essentially little danger in this information being compromised by other users on the machine.

### MySQL user accounts

MySQL has individual user accounts. These are how individual MySQL users authenticate to the database server and generally should not be shared between users, applications, or services. Like system accounts, these passwords are stored in a hashed form that makes it relatively secure so that there is again little danger in other users looking at the hashed password.

### Application passwords

This is the difficult one. Many applications create a user table within the application database in MySQL. This can be incredibly simple; such as a username and plain text password, or can be quite elaborate and secure. Applications such as WordPress, Joomla, phpBB, and virtually everything else implement their own application-level password methods. This may be properly hashed and secure, or it may be plain-text. Without knowing the details of the application, we can't say with certainty. You can get some hint by looking at the password field in the database itself, but this doesn't make it immediately obvious if the password is salted, or hashed with a weak algorithm. Therefore, this is a possible attack vector with which you should probably be concerned.

Another interesting aspect here is network sniffing; an attacker could sniff network traffic to determine a user's MySQL password. A simple workaround is to enforce only SSL-encrypted communications for the users to connect to the MySQL server, and/or only use the socket connection method.

I think that covers on a relatively high level all the possible attack vectors here. I've taken some liberties for the sake of simplifying things; for instance there are some older operating systems that use weakened hashing methods which mean mean those hashes aren't cryptographically secure, and any user with access can probably escalate their privileges (for instance, a user with physical access to the server can restart with another bootable drive, reset the root system password, install whatever keylogger they wish, and restore things. Similar warnings would apply to a user without physical access but with administrative privileges. Depending on your attack vector, these aspects may or may not be of concern to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible....

- All I would need to do is open up the phpMyAdmin configuration file and have a look at the database access information as it is unencrypted there. Basically any configuration setting which is itself not encrypted will be a security issue.

(Once I have DB access which will probably be System Admin (sa) access I could reverse engineer the users and passwords in the system given enough time as I would have access to the salt in the DB as well)

Other scenarios (I don't know your exact setup) would be:

- Checking logs
- Sniffing network traffic for any unsecure DB access. Say you aren't using TLS for instance
- As I also have physical access to the machine I could also crack the OS users and passwords or even add one for my own use for later on

Short answer is that when people have access to the physical machine your attack surface goes up exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the system (OS) passwords, they are all hashed with the salt method. Read full here which takes too long to decrypt.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

But if it's related to phpMyAdmin, that is totally related how you store user's passwords. You might need to store the hash of the passwords, although the phpMyAdmin admins can override their own hashes and access to user's data.